# Why am I getting 'Uncaught TypeError: regex.test is not a function' when used inside another function?

Tags: javascript, function, typeerror

I may just be being thick here but I don't understand why I am receiving this error. Outside of the function the .test() works fine. But inside, I get the error. Was thinking it was something to do with the scope of the .test() function but am I just missing something blindingly obvious here?

```js
     function cFunctionfirst() {
          firstField = document.getElementById("sname_input_first").value;
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "first: " + firstField;

          console.log(firstField);
          var regex = "!@#$£%^&*()+=[]\\\';,./{}|\":<>?";

          if(regex.test(firstField)){
               console.log('illegal characters used');
          } else {
               console.log('Character okay');
          };
     };
```

Answer (score 5):

That's because `regex` is not a `RegExp` object, but just a string. It should be declared as such (remember to escape special characters using `\`):

```
var regex = /[!@#\$£%\^&\*\(\)\+=\[\]\\\';,\.\/\{\}\|":<>\?]/;
```

Not only have I escaped some special regex characters, but you will need to wrap the entire selection inside unescaped `[` and `]` brackets, so that you **test against a set of characters**.

p/s: These are the set characters that need to be escaped: `\ ^ $ * + ? . ( ) | { } [ ]`

See proof-of-concept example:

```js
function cFunctionfirst(value) {
  var regex = /[!@#\$£%\^&\*\(\)\+=\[\]\\\';,\.\/\{\}\|":<>\?]/;
  if(regex.test(value)){
    console.log('illegal characters used');
  } else {
    console.log('Character okay');
  };
};

cFunctionfirst('Legal string');
cFunctionfirst('Illegal string @$%');
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to manually escape the characters, you can either [use a utility method to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6969486/395910), or use an ES6 non-regex approach, which is probably a lot less efficient: [checkout the JSPerf test I have made](https://jsperf.com/regex-vs-es6-array-prototype-some). Simply add the blacklisted characters *literally* in a string, split it, and then use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if the incoming string contains any of the blacklisted characters:

```js
function cFunctionfirst(value) {
  var blacklist = '!@#$£%^&*()+=[]\\\';,./{}|":<>?'.split('');
  if (blacklist.some(char => value.includes(char))) {
    console.log('illegal characters used');
  } else {
    console.log('Character okay');
  };
};

cFunctionfirst('Legal string');
cFunctionfirst('Illegal string @$%');
```